# Возникла проблема с запуском продуктов JetBrains на Linux

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains, datagrip

ОС - Manjaro KDE, установил через aur DataGrip и Idea. Они не запускаются, ошибку, полученную при запуске DataGrip прикладываю. У Idea аналогичная. Подскажите пожалуйста, как с этим можно бороться?

````
Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: UI initialization failed
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$15(StartupUtil.java:265)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:970)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:791)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil (in unnamed module @0x33b37288) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x33b37288
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:787)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil (in unnamed module @0x33b37288) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x33b37288
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$23(StartupUtil.java:507)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:783)
    ... 14 more

-----
Your JRE: 16.0.2+7 amd64 (N/A)
/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk ```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже DataGrip и Idea не готовы к работе на JRE 16 версии.

Поставь яву постарше `jre11-openjdk` или `intellij-idea-community-edition-jre` через aur со встроенной явой.

Для datagrip: у меня работает через `aur/datagrip-jre`.